# WebRTC - Record Video Conference Media Stream in Single File

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webrtc, video-recording, video-conferencing

I am trying to make Video Conference Application with Conference Recording functionality using `WebRTC`. I am very much new to Video Conferencing things and Client-Server Connection scenarios.

I have created a demo application for video conferencing using peer-to-peer connection. which works perfectly. but I also need to record whole conference (video + audio of both the parties) in single file.

What I looked in `WebRTC` demos, I didn't get any such method to do that. I am not sure if I can do it by merging `WebRTC` with any other tool or simply using `WebRTC` with some custom logic.

Please help me on this, I am also open to use any other open source tool if they provide such functionality.

Comment: If you want both video feeds in the same file, you will probably have to do some decoding/reencoding, which is not recommended you do in the browser. I would think a webrtc MCU(janus-gateway or kurento) is your only option

Comment: @BenjaminTrent, can you give me some more detail about jenus-gateway. i have looked at kurento, but its require linux server and java. I need solution with either .net or pure javascript.

Comment: Well, There is not one that is .NET(at least not that I know of). And it depends on your definition of "pure" javascript. You could probably get something to work with node.js but you may have to right your only plugin for the merging of feeds and such.

Answer (score 1):

Different browser is doing thing differently right now.

I think only **Firefox** allows you to create a single file recording right from the WebRTC stream at the moment.

**Chrome** will split the audio and video track and so you have to combine it yourself either using **ffmpeg** like https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/ffmpeg/ on the browser... **NOT RECOMMENDED** or push them to the server and combine it there using fullblown ffmpeg as a background task.

Not too much of an ffmpeg expert, but I think you need to shift the audio like 1 second earlier or 1 second after to properly sync the audio and video stream from my attempt of doing similar thing last time.  Forgot which way.

Basically, you need to feed both the video and audio stream, choose something like webm encoding or mp4 encoding and aac audio or mp3 etc. and output it to a single file.  All I can say is you will have a lot of trial and error to get the right output. Good luck :)

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

or perhaps try something like http://www.kurento.org/ which I think will do this for you.

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy for reply. I suppose, this is procedure for combining video and audio of client web stream. does it require same process to combine video + audio of remote party ?